# javascript form validation not working on website

Tags: javascript, forms, xhtml

I've tried on locahost and it is fine, as i copy the file with ftp to my website for my assignment, it doesnt work.... is there any problems with code below?

here is my xhtml forms code:

```
</p><form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="insert.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="register" >

    <table style="width: 300px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>

    <td>Username: * </td>

    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td> <<one of name forms
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>Password: * </td>

    <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td> <<name of forms
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>Email: * </td>

    <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td> <<name of forms
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> * is must fulfilled </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button value="Submit" type="submit">Submit</button></td>
    <td><button value="Reset" type="reset">Clear</button></td></tr></tbody></table>
            </form>
```

and here is my javascript

```
function validateForm() {
      var y = document.forms["register"]["username"].value;
    if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Username must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
      var z = document.forms["register"]["password"].value;
    if (z == null || z == "") {
        alert("Password must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var x = document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the javascript inline or imported from a file? If it is imported, it may be that the path is broken once you moved the files to the server.

Comment: What does "*it doesn't work*" actually mean?

Comment: the javascript is external file. it doesnt work means the submit button is directing to insert.php instead of validating the page first

Answer (score 0):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="insert.php" name="register" >

    <table style="width: 300px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>

    <td>Username: * </td>

    <td><input type="text" name="username" required/></td> <one of name forms
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>Password: * </td>

    <td><input type="text" name="password" required/></td> <name of forms
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>Email: * </td>

    <td><input type="text" name="email" pattern="^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$./" required></td> <name of forms
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> * is must fulfilled </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button value="Submit" type="submit">Submit</button></td>
    <td><button value="Reset" type="reset">Clear</button></td></tr></tbody></table>
            </form>
```

Comment: @Timothy Herry Susanto, you can do the validation in html, you don't need the validationForm function, did you got it ?